# why connect facebook app return confuse URL

Tags: php, facebook

I have fabrook connect code in PHP like

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET, 'cookie' => true));
 $session = $facebook->getSession();

 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
            'canvas'    => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'req_perms' => 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access',
   'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname/')
 );

if (!$session) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
```

when user access too my application it redirect to facebook permission page. that user must click **Allow** to accept permission request.

when user Allow, my application return sime confuse URL such as

> http://apps.facebook.com/appname/?perms=email%2Cread_stream%2Cpublish_stream%2Coffline_access&selected_profiles=1756044141&installed=1&session={%22session_key%22%d221b6f2-1756044141%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%221756044141%22%2C%22expires%22%3A0%2C%22secret%22%5ffd193f40cc1c3acd%22%2C%22base_domain%22%3A%22muslimsquare.com%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22148835711801079|bdf70ed30-1756044141|wvq6bAErEPdDxMZ.%22%2C%22sig%22%3A%22478a31ffc9dcc55daa19aa0d72}

instead of

> http://apps.facebook.com/appname/

how can i fix it to facebook return clean url (http://apps.facebook.com/appname/)

Answer (score 0):

That is because facebook adds session, application id and more information to the url by default. You can however, decode the url like this:

```
urldecode($url);
```

Comment: @Giffary: You can get the current url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: @@Sarfraz  when i call urldecode($url); ? give me an idea please.

Comment: You simply do this: `$url = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); echo $url;`